# Trying to compile Maven with clean parameter and got exception

Tags: java, maven

Trying to compile Maven with clean parameter:

C:> mvn clean

and got the exception below:

Cannot execute mojo: clean. it requires a project with an existing pom.xml, but the buid is not using one.

can anyone tell me how I can associate my existing project to maven.

Comment: you should go to project directory and try

Answer (score 1):

Maven uses a file called [pom.xml](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) to build.  It should be located in the root of your project.

Maven works on the basis that your project conforms to the Maven way of doing things and so I would recommend reading the [Maven Getting Started Guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html) to familiarize with the standards before starting to use Maven.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read up on a bit of documentation. Basically it is the pom.xml file it is complaining about that defines how maven should handle your project.

[This](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) explains how you can use maven to generate an example project.

[This](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/maven-tutorials/) goes in more depth and also provides some links to other resources.

Comment: from where, I can give the command "mvn package". is this the same location where our pom file available?

Answer (score 0):

suppose your project is in 'C:\MyProject' where you can see a pom.xml file, open command prompt, go to C:\MyProject and type 'mvn clean' as follows:

```
> cd C:\MyProject
> mvn clean
```

Answer (score 0):

The project you are compiling is not a maven project.